# Unable to share a document with external email addresses using "Send http Request to sharepoint"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

Inside the SharePoint Online UI we can share a document with external email using this approach ("People you choose") and grant them Read-Only permission:-

[image]

now i want to do the same inside my power automate flow >> where each client has around 10 documents to be shared, and we do not want to directly email the client for each file >> so inside the flow i want to generate a sharing link for each document >> build an HTML table of all the sharing links and send them to the client all at once.

so i did not find any built-in actions to support this, so i chose to do an http request >> where i tried this approach:-

[image]

here is the body syntax:-

```
{

    "request":{
        "createLink":true,
    "emailData":[ { "Address":"@{items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo1']}"},{ "Address":"@{items('Apply_to_each_-_Certificates_2')?['EmailAddressNo2']}"} ],
        "settings":{
            "allowAnonymousAccess":true,
            "linkKind":6,
            "role":1,

            "restrictShareMembership":false,
            "scope":0
        }
    }
}
```

but i got this exception: -

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.\r\nclientRequestId: 35e4d412-d250-4409-a2d6-df300b399b24\r\nserviceRequestId: d735b2a0-d09d-6000-8828-92a62a1fc550",
  "source": "https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/Certification/_api/web/Lists('d00b93fd-7af1-4985-ba4d-4d957b82f5b2')/GetItemByID('40')/Sharelink",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException"
  ]
}
```

here is sample of the body which is raising an exception:-

```
{

    "request":{
    "createLink":true,
    "emailData":[ { "Address":"****@gmail.com"},{ "Address":"***@yahoo.com"} ],
        "settings":{
            "allowAnonymousAccess":true,
            "linkKind":6,
            "role":1,
            "restrictShareMembership":false,
            "scope":0
        }
    }
}
```

any advice? Thanks